# Error in function rembuff:floor() in lua code file: attempt to call method 'floor' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, torch

In Machine Translation Dataset I have successfully pre-trained my model in Lua. Now I move to train my model.

But I get the error in a Lua file in the function `rembuff:floor()
Error: Attempt to call method 'floor' (a nil value)`

This is that specific function :

```
function MarginBatchBeamSearcher:nextSearchStep(t, batch_pred_inp, batch_ctx, beam_dec, beam_scorer,gold_scores, target, target_w, gold_rnn_state_dec, delts, losses, global_noise)

local K = self.K
local resval, resind, rembuff = self.resval, self.resind, self.rembuff
local finalval, finalind = self.finalval, self.finalind
self:synchDropout(t, global_noise)
-- pred_inp should be what was predicted at the last step
local outs = beam_dec:forward({batch_pred_inp, batch_ctx, unpack(self.prev_state)})
local all_scores = beam_scorer:forward(outs[#outs]) -- should be (batch_l*K) x V matrix
local V = all_scores:size(2)
local mistaken_preds = {}
for n = 1, self.batch_size do
  delts[n] = 0
  losses[n] = 0
  if t <= target_w[n]-1 then -- only do things if t <= length (incl end token) - 2
    local beam_size = #self.pred_pfxs[n]
    local nstart = (n-1)*K+1
    local nend = n*K
    local scores = all_scores:sub(nstart, nstart+beam_size-1):view(-1) -- scores for this example
    -- take top K
    torch.topk(resval, resind, scores, K, 1, true)
    -- see if we violated margin
    torch.min(finalval, finalind, resval, 1) -- resind[finalind[1]] is idx of K'th highest predicted word
    -- checking that true score at least 1 higher than K'th
    losses[n] = math.max(0, 1 - gold_scores[n][target[t+1][n]] + finalval[1])
    -- losses[n] = math.max(0, - gold_scores[n][target[t+1][n]] + finalval[1])
    if losses[n] > 0 then
      local parent_idx = math.ceil(resind[finalind[1]]/V)
      local pred_word = ((resind[finalind[1]]-1)%V) + 1
      mistaken_preds[n] = {prev = self.pred_pfxs[n][parent_idx], val = pred_word}
      delts[n] = 1 -- can change.....
    else
      -- put predicted next words in pred_inp
      rembuff:add(resind, -1) -- set rembuff = resind - 1
      rembuff:div(V)
      --if rembuff.floor then
      rembuff:floor()
```

I am unable to rectify this error : 
Please help !

Comment: When i enter the command to train it starts off like this........................................... loading data... 
done! 
Source vocab size: 32011, Target vocab size: 22824 
Source max sent len: 283, Target max sent len: 285 
layer_etas 0.02 0.02 0.1 
loading mixerpt_epoch3_202.02.t7... 
Number of parameters: 333860

Comment: But gets an error :::: /home/singla/torch/install/bin/luajit: /home/singla/Desktop/Singla/BSO/margin_beam_searcher.lua:106: attempt to call method 'floor' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
 /home/singla/Desktop/Singla/BSO/margin_beam_searcher.lua:106: in function 'nextSearchStep'
 bso_train.lua:536: in function 'train_batch'
 bso_train.lua:666: in function 'train'
 bso_train.lua:953: in function 'main'
 bso_train.lua:956: in main chunk
 [C]: in function 'dofile'
 ...ngla/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
 [C]: at 0x00405d50

Comment: What is the command you ran on the terminal. Please post it

Comment: What happens if you add `rembuff = math.floor(rembuff)`

Comment: Command used for pretrain (Executed successfully) :

th pretrain.lua -data_file data_prep/MT/prep-train.hdf5 -val_data_file data_prep/MT/prep-val.hdf5 -savefile mixerpt -num_layers 1 -rnn_size 4 -word_vec_size 4 -save_after 3 -adagrad -layer_etas 0.02,0.02,0.2 -epochs 3 -curriculum 1 -dropout 0.2

Comment: Command for Train :

th bso_train.lua -data_file data_prep/MT/prep-train.hdf5 -val_data_file data_prep/MT/prep-val.hdf5 -savefile mixersave -num_layers 1 -rnn_size 4 -word_vec_size 4 -save_after 21 -adagrad -curriculum 0 -epochs 21 -train_from mixerpt_epoch3_202.02.t7 -dropout 0.2 -max_beam_size 6 -beam_size 2 -layer_etas 0.02,0.02,0.1 -mt_delt_multiple 1

Comment: When i add   rembuff=math.floor(rembuff)     just before last line rembuff:floor() 
i get the following error :
BSO/margin_beam_searcher.lua:106: bad argument #1 to 'floor' (number expected, got userdata)
stack traceback:
 [C]: in function 'floor'

Comment: what does rembuff contain? Please print and check

Comment: I checked what rembuff contains and printed it 
 print(rembuff.floor) ---It shows nil
 In code it is given that rembuff contains  floor((resind-1)/V)
 So i printed print((resind-1)/V) and it shows 0
 and then i printed  print(floor((resind-1)/V)) and it shows a error here

Comment: This is my edited code part                                                                                           else
          -- put predicted next words in pred_inp
          print("2")
          rembuff:add(resind, -1) -- set rembuff = resind - 1
          rembuff:div(V)
          print((resind-1)/V)
          --if rembuff.floor then
          print("3")
          print(rembuff.floor)
          print(floor((resind-1)/V))
          rembuff:floor()    -- note rembuff contains floor((resind-1)/V)
          --end

Comment: what does `rembuff` contain is still not answered. I am not asking for what does `rembuff.x()` contain.

Comment: [ before the rembuff:add(resind , -1) ]   print(rembuff ) gives  28696704  
                                          8

Comment: Respected Sir ,......As rembuff.floor was nil so i commented out  -- rembuff:floor().....and the error vanished and it started training .........Can you please check and confirm is that right or not ?